# Viewmodel with 2 viewmodels and only one required

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a ViewModel which contains things like payment amount.
The user has the ability to pay by card or by bank account.

I have both viewmodels in the payment view model.

I want to know how it is possible to only be able to "validate" the one payment type viewmodel (either card or bank) when the form is submitted.

I have a jquery accordion thing going on where they can select either card payment or bank payment and upon selection, the div expands and they enter the appropriate information.

each of the payment type div has a Html.BeginForm which then posts to the correct action i.e:

```
<div>
@using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitCardPayment", "Account"))
{
    // submit button here
}
</div>
<div>
@using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitBankPayment", "Account"))
{
    // submit button here
}
</div>
```

I do implement the IValidatableObject in the view model for the card and bank payment view model to do some validation there. But I want to know how can I validate only one of the payment view models here and if there is an error to obviously show it but making sure that the other payment view model is unaffected or prevents it from submitting if details are not entered, since both payment view models have required attributes.

What happens currently is that when there is a submit, I do pass in the entire view model (since the parent view model contains things like the product Id, amount to pay etc...) but along with it comes both payment types view model

thanks

**Update** - I also noticed upon submitting either one of the forms, that the data for the parent view model does not seem to post along with it. Not sure why that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

ok, so the solution that seems to work, but do not thing it is eligent, is the following:

create the main parent VM which contains 2 child models for the payment types.

on form submit post to a different action but giving in a more specific viewmodel (basically the parent view model + the only payment type view model in that context like parent + Bank or parent + card)

then if we have any validation errors etc... we create our main parent VM with the 2 child models, map the properties and return that back to the view.

this does work nicely but think its more work required.